# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '{'

Tags: procedure

I am new to java.We have a few tabled valued parameter used in one of our stored procedure when we try with below code then we are getting following error.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
>   '{'.
>
> import java.sql.*;
>
> import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataTable; import
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement;
>
> public class DB_SP_Call {
>          Connection conn = null;
>        Statement stmt = null;
>        String dbserver="10.42.*.*:1198";
>        String db="t1c";
>        String USER="t1c";
>        String PWD="t1c";
>        String sql;  static final  String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";      public void
>   runSP(){
>             String DB_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+dbserver+";databaseName="+db;       try{
>                     Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
>
> ```
>                   //STEP 3: Open a connection
>               System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
>               conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PWD);
>               System.out.println("Creating statement...");
>               stmt = conn.createStatement();
>               //SQLServerPreparedStatement pstmt = (SQLServerPreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement("{call exec
> ```
>
> t1c.scnTargetingBYO
>   @InstrID=?,@CAS=?,@PageNum=?,@PageSize=?,@SortField=?,@TotalRecNum=?
>   output,@OutputFirmFund=?,@Download=?,@FirmContactData=?,@FirmList=?,@CustTagList=?,@LocationList=?,@Orientation=?,@InvTypeIDList=?,@InvStyleIDList=?,@AdvisoryList=?,@SocialyResposible=?,@TurnoverList=?,@SecurityActivity=?,@InstWithUpside=?,@MarketCapPass=?,@PNI=?,@EventFirmMet=?,@EventType=?,@CorpParticipant=?,@SectorList=?,@GeoIDList=?,@MarketCapStr=?,@HoldType=?,@ActThreshold=?,@SavedDataFlag=?
>   output,@DisplayGroupFlag=?,@PerPeerFlag=?,@UserId=?,@AccountID=?}");
>
> ```
>               SQLServerPreparedStatement pstmt = (SQLServerPreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement("{ call exec
> ```
>
> t1c.scnTargetingBYO
>   ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
>   }");
>                     pstmt.setInt(1, 264998);
>                     pstmt.setString(2, "P");
>                     pstmt.setInt(3,0);
>                     pstmt.setInt(4, 100);
>                     pstmt.setString(5, "Pos DESC");
>                     pstmt.setInt(6, 2308);
>                     pstmt.setInt(7,0);
>                     pstmt.setInt(8, 0);
>                     pstmt.setInt(9, 0);
>
> ```
>               SQLServerDataTable p10 = new SQLServerDataTable(); 
>               p10.addColumnMetadata("ID1",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p10.addColumnMetadata("ID2",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               pstmt.setStructured(10, "t1c.InvIDTabType", p10);
>
>               SQLServerDataTable p11 = new SQLServerDataTable(); 
>               p11.addColumnMetadata("ID1",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p11.addColumnMetadata("ID2",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               pstmt.setStructured(11, "t1c.InvIDTabType", p11);
>
>               SQLServerDataTable p12 = new SQLServerDataTable(); 
>               p12.addColumnMetadata("LocationID",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p12.addColumnMetadata("LocationTypeID",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               Object[] row= new Object[2];
>               row[0]=new Integer(10006);
>               row[1]=new Integer(5);
>               p12.addRow(row);
>               pstmt.setStructured(12, "t1c.LocationList", p12);
>
>               pstmt.setInt(13,1);
>
>               SQLServerDataTable p14 = new SQLServerDataTable();
>               p14.addColumnMetadata("ID1",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p14.addColumnMetadata("ID2",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p14.addColumnMetadata("Lev",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               Object[] row1= new Object[3];
>               row1[0]=new Integer(200);
>               row1[1]=null;
>               row1[2]=new Integer(2);
>               p14.addRow(row1);
>               Object[] row2= new Object[3];
>               row2[0]=new Integer(600);
>               row2[1]=null;
>               row2[2]=new Integer(1);
>               p14.addRow(row2);
>               Object[] row3= new Object[3];
>               row3[0]=new Integer(100);
>               row3[1]=null;
>               row3[2]=new Integer(2);
>               p14.addRow(row3);
>               Object[] row4= new Object[3];
>               row4[0]=new Integer(500);
>               row4[1]=null;
>               row4[2]=new Integer(1);
>               p14.addRow(row4);
>               Object[] row5= new Object[3];
>               row5[0]=new Integer(300);
>               row5[1]=null;
>               row5[2]=new Integer(2);
>               p14.addRow(row5);
>               pstmt.setStructured(14, "t1c.InvIDTabType2", p14);
>
>               SQLServerDataTable p15 = new SQLServerDataTable();
>               p15.addColumnMetadata("ID1",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p15.addColumnMetadata("ID2",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p15.addColumnMetadata("Lev",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               pstmt.setStructured(15, "t1c.InvIDTabType2", p15);
>
>               pstmt.setInt(16,0);
>               pstmt.setString(17,"NULL");
>
>
>
>               SQLServerDataTable p18 = new SQLServerDataTable();
>               p18.addColumnMetadata("ID1",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p18.addColumnMetadata("ID2",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               pstmt.setStructured(18, "t1c.InvIDTabType", p18);
>
>               pstmt.setInt(19,0);
>               pstmt.setInt(20,0);
>               pstmt.setInt(21,0);
>               pstmt.setInt(22,0);
>               pstmt.setInt(23,3);
>
>               SQLServerDataTable p24 = new SQLServerDataTable();
>               p24.addColumnMetadata("EventID",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p24.addColumnMetadata("ID1",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p24.addColumnMetadata("ID2",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               pstmt.setStructured(24, "cms.EvtLinkTabType", p24);
>
>
>               SQLServerDataTable p25 = new SQLServerDataTable();
>               p25.addColumnMetadata("ID1",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p25.addColumnMetadata("ID2",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               pstmt.setStructured(25, "t1c.InvIDTabType", p25);
>
>
>               SQLServerDataTable p26 = new SQLServerDataTable();
>               p26.addColumnMetadata("Type",java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
>               p26.addColumnMetadata("ID",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p26.addColumnMetadata("ID1",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p26.addColumnMetadata("ID2",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p26.addColumnMetadata("ID3",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p26.addColumnMetadata("ID4",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p26.addColumnMetadata("ID5",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p26.addColumnMetadata("ID6",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p26.addColumnMetadata("ID7",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               pstmt.setStructured(26, "t1c.InvSpecialIDTabType2", p26);
>
>
>               SQLServerDataTable p27 = new SQLServerDataTable();
>               p27.addColumnMetadata("Type",java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
>               p27.addColumnMetadata("ID",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p27.addColumnMetadata("ID1",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p27.addColumnMetadata("ID2",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p27.addColumnMetadata("ID3",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p27.addColumnMetadata("ID4",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p27.addColumnMetadata("ID5",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p27.addColumnMetadata("ID6",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p27.addColumnMetadata("ID7",java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               pstmt.setStructured(27, "t1c.InvSpecialIDTabType2", p27);
>
>               pstmt.setString(28,"NULL");
>               pstmt.setInt(29,1);
>
>               SQLServerDataTable p30 = new SQLServerDataTable();
>               p30.addColumnMetadata("Category", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
>               p30.addColumnMetadata("ActType", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p30.addColumnMetadata("Threshold", java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
>               p30.addColumnMetadata("Min", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>               p30.addColumnMetadata("Max", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
>
>               Object[] row6= new Object[5];
>               row6[0]=new String("O");
>               row6[1]=new Integer(0);
>               row6[2]=new String("S");
>               row6[3]=new Integer(1);
>               row6[4]=null;
>               p30.addRow(row6);
>               Object[] row7= new Object[5];
>               row7[0]=new String("F");
>               row7[1]=null;
>               row7[2]=new String("E");
>               row7[3]=new Integer(5);
>               row7[4]=null;
>               p30.addRow(row7);
>               pstmt.setStructured(30, "t1c.InvActThresholdTabType", p30);
>
>               pstmt.setInt(31,2);
>               pstmt.setInt(32,2946);
>               pstmt.setInt(33,0);
>               pstmt.setInt(34,234568);
>               pstmt.setInt(35,21022);
>
>
>               ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
>               //ResultSet rs = pstmt.execute();
>                 ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
>                 //System.out.println("Hi, fetching resultset.........");
>                 System.out.println(metaData.getColumnCount());
>
>                 while(rs.next()){
>
>
>                    int intdata  = rs.getInt("LgcyInvestorID");
>                    System.out.println(intdata);
>                 }
>
>       }catch(Exception e){            e.printStackTrace();
>
>           }finally{
>         //finally block used to close resources
>         try{
>                      if(stmt!=null)
>                      stmt.close();
>                }
>
>         catch(SQLException se2)
>         {
>         }// nothing we can do
>         try{
>               if(conn!=null)
>               conn.close();
>         }catch(SQLException se){
>           se.printStackTrace();
>         }//end finally try
>
>    }
>                           }
> ```
>
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>                 DB_SP_Call dbcall= new DB_SP_Call();
>                 dbcall.runSP();     }
>
> }

Request experts to please help in this regard.

Comment: I would suggest to refactor your code first of all. Then what's suggested is pretty obvious, you are missing a "}" at the end of your DB_SP_Call  class

Comment: I modified the prepared statement and removed {call} and just gave exec statement. After that I could see in SQL server trace that the sp got executed. When I copied and ran the SP in SQL management I got the error "Must have @name=value" pair after certain parameter. Now my question how do we pass @name=value pair for non table valued parameters. pstmt.setInt(1,264988) results in just replacing ? with 264988 where as we want the same to be replaced with @InstrID=264988 as SP parameter. Can anyone please help how to do the same in Java?